# Diferencia entre objetoJDialog.getContentPane().setBackground() y objetoJDialog.setBackground()

Tags: java

La pregunta es simple, quiero saber porque con el getContentPane() se produce el cambio de color del fondo y sin el no.

```
    NotaJDialog njd = new NotaJDialog (this,true);
    njd.setResizable(false);
    njd.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
    njd.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    njd.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, al poner `njd.getContentPane()` estás llamando al contenedor del `NotaJDialog`, es decir, si tu has metido al `NotaJDialog` dentro de un JPanel al ponerle la primera instrucción de tu pregunta estas cambiando el color de fondo en el padre de `NotaJDialog`.

Por otra parte, en la otra instrucción estás cambiando el color al `NotaJDialog`.

Te dejo la [documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane()).

Únicamente podremos cambiar-lo llamando al contenedor

```
.getContentPane()
```

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4092995[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4092995)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. El JDialog lo estoy instanciando en un Jframe, y no en JPanel. La primera instrucción "njd.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red)" lo que me cambian es color de fondo del JDialog cuando pulso un botón "abrir" JDialog, este se abre en forma de ventana con el color de fondo rojo.

Comment: De nada, he puesto JPanel como ejemplo. :)

Comment: xD es que no me ha quedado claro del todo. Porque tu dices que la primera instruccion cambia el fondo del padre, en este caso el padre seria JFrame y cuando ejecuto el programa no cambia el padre si no JDialog y el otro código es como si no pasase nada. Bueno todas maneras gracias.

Comment: Verás, segun la documentación oficial, lo que hace es devolverte el contenedor donde tienes el objeto, en este caso sería el JFrame

Comment: Eso lo entiendo. Pero a lo que yo me voy es que que pasa con la otra instrucción no hace nada, no me cambia ningún fondo.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno me respondo yo mismo ya que creo que la respuesta es esta.

Primero saber que un JFrame esta formado o compuesto por varias capas. Como lo pone en esta imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde realmente se sitúa los componentes es en este contenedor llamado ContentPane y como pone claramente en la imagen es sobre el que realmente se trabaja. Por eso para poder agregar o hacer modificaciones se hace sobre este contenedor. Entonces como logro acceder a mi contenedor y poder cambiar por ejemplo el color de fondo? Pues mediante el método getContentPane. A partir de el recién podre cambiar el fondo del JFrame o JDialog que viene a ser casi lo mismo. Ejemplo:

```
  NombreJFrame objetoJFrame = new NombreJFrame (this,true);
  objetoJFrame.setBackground(Color.red); // De esta forma no estamos cambiando el color de fondo ya que no estamos trabajando sobre el contenedor donde se ubica los elementos
  objetoJFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue); // Como estamos obteniendo el contenedor del JFrame y es realmente donde se trabaja con los elementos, si que estariamos cambiando el color de fondo.
```

Aqui dejo otra imagen para poder aclararlo mas.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]